# hide/show parameter2 based on parameter1 value in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny apps/R and would require your help to address my below scenario.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "para1",label = "parameter1", choices = c("var1","Var2")),
  selectInput(inputId = "para2",label = "parameter2", choices = c("cars","trucks"))
)
server <- function(input,output,session){
  output$text <- renderText("control parameters")
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

my requirement is to show/hide "parameter2" based on selecting the "parameter1" values.
Let's say if I select `parameter1=="var1"`, then show "parameter2" otherwise hide entire "parameter2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `shinyjs::toggle` combined with `uiOutput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  selectInput(inputId = "para1",label = "parameter1", choices = c("var1","var2")),
  uiOutput("selectPara2")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  output$selectPara2 <- renderUI(selectInput(inputId = "para2",label = "parameter2", choices = c("cars","trucks"))) 
  
  shiny::observeEvent(input$para1, {
    shinyjs::toggle("selectPara2", condition = input$para1 == "var1")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

note that `useShinyjs()` needs to be called in the `UI` for this to work.